# Can I generate CSR using java keytool on Computer 1, and use that keystore on Computer 2?

Tags: keystore, keytool

Assuming I have created a keystore and private key using java keytool using the following command on Computer 1.

keytool -genkey -dname "CN=abc" -alias abc -keyalg "RSA" -keysize 1024 -sigalg "SHA256WITHRSA" -validity 365 -keystore "DEF.jks"

Then I use portecle to open this keystore and generate Cert Request

After I import CA reply, can I use that keystore(.jks) file on Computer 2?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can use the keystore on Computer 2. It is just a file from a file system point of view.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but the reason that most guides you will see do not do it that way is that it's easier to keep your secret key secure if you don't make copies of it or transfer it over networks. If you generate your CSR on the computer that is going to use the certificate, then you don't need to make copies. The issued certificate cannot be used without the secret key, so it's safer to transmit the CSR and the certificate around, while the secret key stays in one place.